# element UI el-collapse in front if others components

Tags: css, vue.js, element-ui

This is my el-collapse:

```
<template>
  <div id="realtime">
    <el-row>
      <el-collapse accordion>
        <el-collapse-item name="1" class="spy-infobar-collapse">
          <template slot="title">
            Consistency<i class="header-icon el-icon-info"></i>
          </template>
          <div>Consistent with real life: in line with the process and logic of real life, and comply with languages and habits that the users are used to;</div>
          <div>Consistent within interface: all elements should be consistent, such as: design style, icons and texts, position of elements, etc.</div>
        </el-collapse-item>
      </el-collapse>
    </el-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

Close
[image]

Open
[image]

I would like to open it over the other components (avoiding to move the below table to the right)

This is my layout

```
<template>
  <div class="app-wrapper" :class="classObj">
    <div v-if="device==='mobile'&&sidebar.opened" class="drawer-bg" @click="handleClickOutside"></div>
    <sidebar class="sidebar-container"></sidebar>
    <div class="main-container">
      <navbar></navbar>
      <info-bar></info-bar>
      <app-main></app-main>
      <vue-snotify></vue-snotify>
      <back-to-top bottom="50px" right="50px">
        <div class="spy-back-to-top" style=""><i class="el-icon-caret-top"></i></div>
      </back-to-top>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`el-collapse` is in the info-bar section, the table is in the app-main section

Is it possible? If not, do you know a vue.js component that could do it?

Comment: Where is your table code? If it's in the same row element, move it out. Please see https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout.

Comment: I updated the question addind info about the layout. el-collapse in in the info-bar, the table in the app-main

Comment: Then it should works fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/5wonoq3jl. The problem must be in your style. Is `main-container` has a flex display or `info-bar` has a float value?

Comment: Thanks @User28 using you code means that I have to extend it for all the line, because currently th collapse takes only a part of the row. I was wondering if there is a way to have it expands over the table instead of pushing it down/right

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/l7y4o381yl. It can be done in many ways so if you have problem with this approach don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @User28 amazing, exactly what I'm searching for. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

```
<style>
.el-collapse-item {
  position: relative;
}

.el-collapse-item__wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.el-collapse-item__content {
  user-select: none;
}

</style>
```